# Issue with getting nav to be swipeable with swipeLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

I am not sure if this is the best way to get a navigation menu to be 'swipeable', if not, I am open to suggestions.

What I am trying to do is get the menu to not show on page load, so I added `margin-left: 101%;`, then when I add the class `swipeleft` I change the `margin-left: 50%` in order for the entire width of the menu to show. However, putting the menu off page like this, I cannot get the menu to swipe in. Does anyone know what I can do to get this to work?

I created a fiddle to show this. Click [here to see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6kbkjsg/)

JS

```
$(function(){
  // Bind the swipeleftHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
  $( "div.box" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

  // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swipeleft' class to it
  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    $( event.target ).addClass( "swipeleft" );
  }
});
```

CSS

```
  div.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 3em;
    background: #108040;
    margin-left: 101%;
  }
  div.box.swipeleft {
    background: #7ACEF4;
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure why the function isn't loading in the fiddle. It loads on my page. ie: I changed the `margin-left: 101%;` to 99% for instance, you will see it works. Just not when it is off screen. http://farleysharley.com/swipe

Comment: It's working with the exact same code in jQuery's documentation. https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup This is jquery's exact code. I just tweaked the code to try and get this off the page and then on the page on swipe.

Comment: This is defilingly odd.  Here's another fiddle i found that is doing the same thing just using `pageinit`, but that doesn't work with your code either...  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kNd8s/

Comment: My swipeleft works...just not when off of the page.

Comment: Are you using the `meta viewport` tag? I wonder if it has anything to do with that?

Comment: Yes, I am. I literally copy and pasted jQuery's code for this into a new file and solely just changed the margin for the div.

Comment: That's what I mean.  Try removing the viewport tag and see if it works off screen.

Comment: Removing the meta viewport did not help.